# How can I Recover my Lost Bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core

how can i recover 3.617BTC i Lost to This investment Website ,

i invested in bitcoin on the website ""Coinfoxltd.com"" through  one of their account mangers Julia Adam.
I tried to withdraw my profit after 2 months, i was told to pay withdrawal fee$1500, which i did then I tried withdraw my profit then i was asked to make another $964 payment for Tax which i did, when i tried to withdraw again i was asked to make another deposit, i think i am been scammed.

Please how can i recover my money from this fake website???

Comment: You can't, you got scammed. If you sent them dollars there would be a chance the bank could trace where it went and the police could get it back. But for bitcoins? Not a chance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are basically unable to withdraw your BTC because you have been scammed. There is no BTC on its website at all. You cannot withdraw your BTC or money. This will not happen if you buy from a proper organization. For example, you will not be deceived when you invest in a formal platform like Coinbase or Binance. So don't trust the fake investment institutions on the Internet.